# jQuery width function is giving zero value for td

Tags: jquery, html-table

I just want to get the table column width after the table loads, so that I can remove the extra white spaces in the column and make it look compact. All I want table cell should take only the width it required to contain it's data.

Table structure is like this:

```
<table style="display: table;"> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <th>word</th>
            <th>%</th>
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <th>word</th> 
            <td><span class="count" style="display:block"> 1</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 2.6%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>word - word word word</th> 
            <td><span class="count" style="display:block"> 1</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 2.6%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>word - word word word word word</th> 
            <td> 1</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 2.6%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>word - word word</th> 
            <td> 2</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 5.1%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>word - word word word</th> 
            <td><span class="count" style="display:block"> 1</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 2.6%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>word - word word word word</th> 
            <td><span class="count" style="display:block"> 1</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 2.6%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>word - word word word</th> 
            <td><span class="count" style="display:block"> 2</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 5.1%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>word - word word</th> 
            <td><span class="count" style="display:block"> 3</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 7.7%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>word - word word</th> 
            <td><span class="count" style="display:block"> 25</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 64.1%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th>word</th> 
            <td> 2</span></td>
            <td><span class="percentage" style="display: block;"> 5.1%</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You will have to show your relevant HTML and code.  We can't divine how to help you without it.

Comment: I'm trying to visualize what you're trying to do, and I think the page would look better if the table width stayed the same regardless of the content.

Comment: You ahve some problem with your css perhaps. Otherwise by default html table columns take space only as much as the maximum content any td

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $("table td:eq(0)").width();
    console.log(width);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I **guess,** you have to use **[$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)** like,

```
$('table tbody td').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).width()); // to get the column width
   trimmedText= $.trim($(this).text());
   $(this).text(trimmedText)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have some problem with your css perhaps. Otherwise by default html table columns take space only as much as the maximum content any td

I think you dont need to get width perhaps you could only trim (remove white spaces) all the texts in your table like Rohan has told

[**JSFIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3JCmY/)

```
var allTds = $('table tbody td');
for(i=0;i<allTds.length;i++)
{
   trimmedText= allTds.eq(i).text();
   allTds.eq(i).text(trimmedText)
}
```

To get width whidth perhaps not needed to you

```
var firstRowTds = $('table tr').eq(0).children();
for(i=0;i<firstRowTds.length;i++)
{
   alert(firstRowTds.eq(i).width()); // column width
}
```